# Very basic syntax error, lines not drawing in d3

Tags: d3.js

For some reason, in the last block of this code `append("g)` us successful, but the data bind to append lines is not. I know should just print 10 lines on top of each other, but I cannot even get them to print into the page for some reason. Can anyone see the error? Thanks very much for your help!

```
var w = 300;

var dataset = 10;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", w);

svg.append("line")
  .attr("x1", w/2)
  .attr("y1", 0)
  .attr("x2", w/2)
  .attr("y2", w);

svg.append("line")
  .attr("x1", 0)
  .attr("y1", w/2)
  .attr("x2", w)
  .attr("y2", w/2);

  svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("x1", 0)
  .attr("y1", w/4)
  .attr("x2", w/2)
  .attr("y2", w/4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataset` in `.data(dataset)` has to be an array so you get nothing. If you use, for example `.data([dataset])` you will get one line. If you want 10 lines you can use `.data(d3.range(10))` and add some color to see it/them:

```
svg.append("g").selectAll("line")
    .data(d3.range(10))
    .enter()
    .append("line")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", w/4)
        .attr("x2", w/2)
        .attr("y2", w/4)
        .style('stroke', 'green');
```

Comment: Thanks Anto! I didn't know about the .range function. Very useful.